# Modelling dialog in web ui with LUIS AI

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

Imagine having a business process where 3 inputs are required. In the worst case the bot has to ask 3 questions and in the best case the user gives us all required information in his/her first message.

Is it possible to build those kind of conversation flows in the luis.ai interface (similar to Amazon Lex) or does it have to be hard coded?

Comment: You may be interested in Adaptive Cards

Comment: @KyleDelaney Although Adaptive Cards are a nice feature I doubt it can help me with my problem.

Comment: It sounds like you want the user to give the bot three pieces of information at once. Is that not the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible in LUIS if you are using Bot Framework proper. LUIS simply does the intent and entity recognition and cannot, on its own, drive a dialog flow.

I don't have a lot of personal experience with it, but Power Virtual Agents may be able to do what you want. There is some information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-virtual-agents/advanced-entities-slot-filling#:%7E:text=response%2C%20if%20necessary.-,Slot%20filling,entity%20value%20into%20a%20variable.). It is certainly possible to code it as well, though I know that isn't what you were asking. You just check on the step if entity exists, if so go to the next step, if not prompt the user. Managing your variables at each step can get a bit tricky this way though, as you do not want to assign `stepContext.value` to something if you skipped the prompt.